# Storing encryption key for use in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, key

I am storing very sensitive information which can be accessed through a php interface. I am currently working on where to store the encryption key. One idea is to store it outside the www folder, storing it in the database is not an option.

Any idea's how this can be done? My idea is that I create a file outside the www folder and only make that file accessable by the webbserver then I load the key from it with PHP and decrypt the data.

How should this key be generated?

Comment: I tried to answer a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19679151/575765 . @YUNOWORK Be careful with such jokes, there is always somebody who takes them seriously...

Comment: @YUNOWORK I think you would be better off alerting it. The user would never think that an alert would contain the encryption key.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't define the key in a PHP file outside of WWW and then just include that?

```
... /home/martin/keys/encryptionkey.php
<?php 

$SUPER_SECRET_KEY = "abcdefg";

?>
```

And then in your main code

```
include("/home/martin/keys/encryptionkey.php");
echo $SUPER_SECRET_KEY;
```

Regarding how to generate the key it has a strong dependancy on the type of encryption you are using. Check the relevant PHP documentation. It is usually sensible to have a reasonably long randomly generated key.

The example on `mcrypt_encrypt` uses:

```
$key = pack('H*', "bcb04b7e103a0cd8b54763051cef08bc55abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffb2a00a3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh, encryption and security on the web is very very complex matter and quite out of the scope of this question.

In general, you can't protect your data just like that. You need to consider many other factors involved in data protection, starting from physical security of server, network security, application security, used encryption algorithm and many other things.

If you really care about your data, start reading first articles on this web site:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10

Then watch for example this video to see how bad it is!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgtkzjR-9G8#t=0